# Can I have a WCF application that has two endpoints. One with Windows Security and one without?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-4

I have read several posts (here on SO and on MSDN) that supposedly show how I can have two endpoints for my WCF service.  But and I can't seem to get this to work.  I tried what they show, but it still does not work.

Here is what I have now:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="MyServiceProject.MyServiceClass">
      <endpoint address="MyService.svc"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingName="normalBasicHttpBinding"
                  contract="MyContractsProject.IMyServiceClass" />

        <endpoint address="SecuredMyService.svc"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingName="secureBasicHttpBinding"
                  contract="MyContractsProject.IMyServiceClass" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="normalBasicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="5242880"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="5242880"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
              <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="16384"
                            maxStringContentLength="5242880" />
          </binding>

        <binding name="secureBasicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="5242880"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="5242880"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxStringContentLength="5242880" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Variations on this that I have tried:

- Taking out the security
- Having the first address be blank and the second just "secure" then going to `http://MyNormalEndpoint/MyService.svc/secure` (was blank and WCF Storm could not connect)
- Adding a <`Host>` section that is a hard reference to the deploy path.  (I don't want to do this as my service has to deploy to several different locations.  But it did not work anyway)
- Having just one endpoint (the secure one)
- Using two different binding types (wsHttpBinding).

None of these has worked.

And now calls to my normal service are returning 404.  (So I have messed something up).  If you want to see my original (working) config it can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/4004836).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have proper formats for address

[Specifying an Endpoint Address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749.aspx)